# Функции из <algorithm> в borland turbo c++

Tags: c++, include, borland

На древнем *borland turbo c++* для *dos* надо запустить программу, которая, предположим, сортирует массив. Насколько я знаю, в *borland turbo c++* заголовочного файла с названием "*algorithm*" нет.

В таком случае, какую библиотеку сюда подключать?

Comment: Хм, что-то я сомневаюсь, что получится подключить что-нибудь из современной стандартной библиотеки — C++ с тех пор сильно вырос.

Comment: @VladD, как минимум, оно не умеет шаблоны. Вообще. Так что, не просто трудно, а очень сильно трудно :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вам нужна сортировка, то вы можете использовать стандартную C библиотеку `<stdlib.h>` и использовать функцию `qsort`.

Думаю, что и в библиотеках Turbo C++ также где-нибудь определена функция `sort`. Если я не ошибаюсь, то в Turbo C++ входит Turbo Vision. Вы можете посмотреть библиотеки этого пакета.

Также в Turbo C++ должна входить встроенная онлайн документация. И кроме того вы можете поискать в интернет соответствующий материал.

Можно найти список заголовочных файлов. Сортировка может быть в заголовке `<search.h>` , если таковой имеется:).

Comment: @R.Abdulaev Я когда просматривал интернет по ключевому выражению "Turbo C++ headers", то нашел ссылку, где можно бесплатно скачать какой-то более новый Turbo C++^) Посмотрите, может быть вам это будет полезно.

Comment: проблема в том, что мне нужно написать код именно под старенький MS-Dos.

Answer (score 2):

Как минимум все заголовочники в BC++ имеют расширение .h и нет namespace'ов.

В версии BC++ 3.1 (не Turbo) действительно нет algorithm.h, так что выкручиваться другими доступными способами, к примеру, используя stdlib.h + qsort. Если не изменяет память, то всякие STLport саппортят борландовский компилятор только версии с пятой.

Ну и десерт: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961828/why-not-to-use-turbo-c

> Turbo C is a real real old, and an ancient compiler

и далее:

> Besides, there are lots of problems with Turbo C++(Im kinda sure TC3
>   is being used). I have no idea absolutely how you are going to
>   convince them! :P
>
> - Its 16 bit (Since I am also from Mumbai University, I am pretty much    sure, you people must be using TC3; 32 bit version of the
>     compiler is    also avaible)
> - The maximum amount of memory that a program can use is 2^16 = 64 KB, which is very small as compared to modern day programs!
>
>   - The programs are more like console based -- ie, I doubt if you can make real great programs using it.
>   - Debugging is not as efficient as they are in other IDEs
>   - It does not conform with the standards that are laid down
>   - You can never learn the concepts like exceptions, templates (which are now at the heart of C++ ) and like with TurboC++
>   - The compiler does not support modern casts, only C-Style casts.
>   - No STL
>   - And I doubt if it goes well with 3rd party libraries! eg database or graphics libraries.
>   - The compiler has bugs and does not issue proper diagnostic messages for erroneous programs.
>   - You end up learning C with classes instead of C++ (kind of) :D :P